# Even after typing the required text in the `blockquote` field the validation message is not going away

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

Even after typing the required text in the `blockquote` field the validation message is not going away, couldn't figure about the issue here, could someone please advise me ! I am using react hook forms in my app. Is it because blockquote is not supported ?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const [createCode, setCreateCode] = useState([{ value: null }]);


 function handleRemoveCode(i) {
        const codeValues = [...createCode];
        codeValues.splice(i, 1);
        setCreateCode(codeValues);
    }
    function handleChangeCode(i, event) {
        const codeValues = [...createCode];
        codeValues[i].value = event.currentTarget.innerText;
        setCreateCode(codeValues);
    }

    <div className='row'>
         {createCode.map((code, idx) => {
             return (
                 <div key={`${code}-${idx}`} className="dCodeArea">
                     <button type="button" onClick={() => handleRemoveCode(idx)} className="closeElement">
                                                        X
                     </button>
                     <blockquote
                     type="text"
                     id="blogcode"
                     name="blogcode"
                     contentEditable='true'
                     placeholder="Enter your code here"
                     className="codehighlight"
                     {...register("blogcode", {
                      required: true,
                      minLength: {
                      value: 5,
                       message: "Minimum length of code is 5"
                       }
                     })}
                     value={code.value || ""}
                     onInput={e => handleChangeCode(idx, e)}
                    />
                     <span className="validationmsg">
                        {errors.blogcode && errors.blogcode.type === "required" && <span>Blog code is required !</span>}
                        {errors.blogcode && <span>{errors.blogcode.message}</span>}
                     </span>
                </div>
            );
        })}
    </div>
```